# I am developing a carplay client for Automotive head unit. Need help for Bonjour

Tags: carplay

I am developing a carplay client for Automotive head unit. I am stuck in Bonjour discovery procedure. This can be easily done if I get the CarPlay Communication Plug-in. Can any one provide me the same.

In bonjour advertisement TXT RECORD filed we have to provide:
Feature field. The correct value for this field is in communication plugin.
I will be highly obliged for this favor.

I can help lower layers of this project.

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to write app for car play. Any help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get  CarPlay Communication Plug-in,you need to get the copyright of apple.